# "Method has not yet been implemented" error when using ActionChains for Appium iOS automation

Tags: python, selenium, mobile, automation, appium

I currently have scripts for web browser automation for my web app, and I am trying to implement those scripts for mobile automation. Everything seems to work, but my code will exit where I implemented ‘ActionChains’ and I receive the error that “Method has not yet been implemented.” Is ActionChains not compatible with Appium?

Also, I tried using TouchAction in place of Action Chains, but it gives me errors such as

```
AttributeError: ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘id’

‘Str’ object has no attribute ‘id’
```

I saw somewhere that TouchAction only works in a native context. I am trying to test my web app on an iPad, so does TouchAction not support web context?

Comment: Post the relevant code please

Comment: "Method has not yet been implemented" means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , TouchAction only simulates "physical" touch or gestures to the screen , it has no correlation to what is happening on the back-end .
For the ActionChains , i believe you need to make some tweaks to make it work on mobile :

```
'driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride', {height:y, width:x}) # height and width of screen
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride', emulation)

config, enabled = 'mobile', True
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse', {'enabled': enabled, 'configuration': config})

maxpoints = 3
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled', {'enabled': enabled, 'maxTouchPoints': maxpoints})'
```

Maybe these will work !